# Applying round/rotation effect in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, adobe-after-effects, illustrator-effects, graphic-styles

[image: Logo of Lion]

I am new in graphic design. I want to ask which effect created the round hair of lion above?

And how colors were managed this way? I am trying transform but it rotates hair completely.

Comment: There is no effect. The hair is made from duplicated and rotated shapes which have been filled with gradients. There's nothing in Illustrator that will do this automatically if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

As already said by others, there's no 1-click way to this. The parts of the hair are separate shapes and they have complex colorings.

The rotation and reshaping the parts is possible with effects, but an artist who knows beforehand what he wants can well be without them.

Here's some tricks:

[image]

1. One hair element. It's actually two circles combined with pathfinder panel's "Minus front"
2. Several copies are made by rotating around the cusp point. The rotations are equally spaced. Making one and clicking Ctrl+D creates the rest one by one.
3. Reshaping with Envelope Distortion. The rotated shapes are grouped and A top shape (=distorted square) is inserted, Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object is used, the result is tweaked with the direct selection tool
4. The Envelope Distortion is expanded, ungrouped and a couple of the shapes are colored. Your example has complex gradients.

Comment: This is a very satisfactory answer. Good job. Question's example has as well a Bevel & Emboss effect to it. Which makes each shape stand out from each other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) As I am beginner so i did not completely understand step 3 of reshaping using envelope distortion of your answer, can you elaborate that as ,my result after using envelope distortion distort hair completely. this can be done manually but i am learning professional way to make shapes.

Comment: Reshaping is a fake imitation to create illusion the hair parts were all drawn individually. The waterproof way: Select the hair shapes. Group them to be sure they keep together. Check by moving or deleting they are all selected. Undo!  Goto Object > Envelope distort > Make with mesh > 1 column, 1 row, use the direct selection tool to adjust corners and curvature handles. Finally Object>Envelope distort>Expand, Ungroup twice to make the parts free.

Comment: Not done precisely but got the idea. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because each individual piece of "hair" is a **different shape**, this was most likely done **manually** by creating the shapes and positioning them accordingly. This does not appear to be any "effect".

One thing is for certain, you *can't* get any sort of rotation effect to also alter the overall shape of objects in the manner shown in that image.

Gradients were then applied to each piece of "hair" to match the desired appearance, again no "effect".